# Laravel composer install hangs on "Installing dependencies" and consume a lot of resources (CPU, DISK)

Tags: installation, laravel-4, ubuntu-12.04, composer-php, php

### Problem 1:

I tried install laravel 4 on my server (Ubuntu 12.04, nginx, php5-fpm) but installation hangs:

```
# composer install --verbose
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
```

- no errors, no nothing, it's just hangs and that's all. 
I've tried installation using `composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist`
...and result was pretty the same:

```
Installing laravel/laravel (v4.0.9)
- Installing laravel/laravel (v4.0.9)
Loading from cache

Created project in /var/www/laravel/ex2/laravel
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev)
```

I couldn't find any ideas/solutions.

Could anyone please tell me what is the problem and how could I fix it?

### Problem 2:

@antonio-carlos-ribeiro was right, I just need to wait. But now I've got another problem:

Installation takes more than 30 minutes! And a lot of resources (CPU and DISK usage)... unbelievable amount of resources. 
Here is graphs of CPU and DISK read/write:
[image: Disk read/write and CPU usage]
I guess it's not normal behavior. Any ideas what is going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

This is Composer being slow. **You need to wait for it** and, yeah, it may be a lot of time.

You also can try to download the packages one by one, installing Laravel "manually"

Create your directory and enter it:

```
mkdir /var/www/laravel/ex2/laravel
cd /var/www/laravel/ex2/laravel
```

Dowload all packages ony by one:

```
composer require filp/whoops 1.0.7
composer require nikic/php-parser dev-master#700847e
composer require jeremeamia/superclosure 1.0.1
composer require doctrine/lexer dev-master#bc0e1f0
composer require doctrine/annotations v1.1.2
composer require doctrine/collections dev-master#bcb5377
composer require doctrine/cache v1.3.0
composer require doctrine/inflector dev-master#8b4b3cc
composer require doctrine/common dev-master#d9dea98
composer require doctrine/dbal 2.4.x-dev#9efdbce
composer require psr/log 1.0.0
composer require monolog/monolog dev-master#a501075
composer require symfony/translation 2.3.x-dev#6aedcff
composer require symfony/routing 2.3.x-dev#7d41463
composer require symfony/process 2.3.x-dev#8289810
composer require symfony/debug 2.3.x-dev#085d4fd
composer require symfony/http-foundation 2.3.x-dev#796619f
composer require symfony/event-dispatcher 2.3.x-dev#2d8ece3
composer require symfony/http-kernel 2.3.x-dev#9795c9f
composer require symfony/finder 2.3.x-dev#a175521
composer require symfony/dom-crawler 2.3.x-dev#4dc2c59
composer require symfony/css-selector 2.3.x-dev#8df20c5
composer require symfony/console 2.3.x-dev#f880062
composer require symfony/browser-kit 2.3.x-dev#7fc66ea
composer require symfony/filesystem dev-master#e558fd5
composer require swiftmailer/swiftmailer v5.0.2
composer require predis/predis 0.8.x-dev#ff004ae
composer require patchwork/utf8 v1.1.14
composer require nesbot/carbon 1.4.0
composer require ircmaxell/password-compat 1.0.x-dev#1fc1521
composer require classpreloader/classpreloader 1.0.1
```

Finally download Laravel

```
composer require laravel/framework 4.0.x-dev
composer require laravel/laravel 4.0.x
```

Move it to the right place

```
mv -f vendor/laravel/laravel/* .
mv -f vendor/laravel/laravel/.g* .
rm -rf vendor/laravel/laravel
```

And execute this to fix your composer.lock

```
composer update
```

After downloading the packages, Composer will cache them in your home folder, so next install you don't have to download all of them manually, unless, of course, some are updated.

**Note:** this is will work only for Laravel 4.0.9, since some of those packages are "marked" to download an specific commit (example: #700847e).

Comment: Thanks. It finally happend :) But it takes more than 30 minutes! And a lot of resources (CPU and DISK usage)... unbelievable amount of resources. Here is graphs of CPU and DISK read/write: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gx2excfbae57guo/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202013-11-07%2018.08.11.png I gues it not normal behavior Any Ideas what is going on?

Comment: I'm doing the same thing for me now on an EC2 server and it's over 20 minutes now. I'm not use to composer taking this long. :(

Comment: @Foxinni Your ref: Deploying with composer on EC2 instances small and micro is awfully slow once your project gets "big enough". Changing the instance type to t3-medium seems to be a whole lot faster.

Comment: Or you could simply create an archive of the `vendor` directory and upload it to your machine instead of using `composer install`. I believe it would save a lot of time. :)

Answer (score 9):

For me was composer vendor. I did just `composer -vvv update`

Comment: its actually not hangs, with -vvv command we can see that its downloading

Answer (score 4):

I was installing it on a windows machine in xampp directory and found that it was hanged while the Apache was running and when i stopped the Apache it starts immediately and ends in some in secs.

Comment: This solved my problem, I stopped apache service and it worked dont know why.

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar issue that `Composer` was hanging and leaving it for more than an hour did not help. I executed `composer -vvv update` and from the resulting log I saw that the requests to github were giving a response of 401, authentication failed.

I resolved it by logging into `Github` and generating a new OAuth token [over here](https://github.com/settings/tokens). I then copied the token and pasted it into this command:

```
composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <oauthtoken>
```

After executing this command, `composer install` then worked correctly and completed in less than a minute.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you are not having xdebug enabled by default. If you have, turn it off.

I had the similar problem where loading JSON dependencies took an hour (for Laravel). After turning off xdebug for cli everything loads in  several seconds!

Comment: Exactly the issue (HP 5.6 on Windows, Laravel 5 for further information on my situation), removed xdebug lines from php.ini whilst running composer and it only took about 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I have found a new answer.

My `php-cli`  did not have `php-curl` extension enabled.

Installing and enabling it did the trick.

Comment: yes you are right this was the main issue i faced in ubuntu. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks it is fixed my issue, after installing php extensions like curl, ftp, gd, dom the issue fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you have un-resolvable dependencies:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of
>   packages.

As the others have mentioned you may need to just run `composer install` and wait. If the dependencies cannot be resolved, composer will scan every possible option - which may take a long time.

If you have lots of dependencies - you might want to try and remove everything from `composer.json` first, then add them back in one at a time to discover which ones are failing to resolve.

When `composer install` eventually finishes - read the output carefully, and see if there are missing dependencies you need to install manually.

In my case I was only trying to install a single package. This was my `composer.json`:

```
{
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^8"
}
```

`composer install` took a long time to run but eventually reported:

```
  Problem 1
- phpunit/phpunit 8.5.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.5.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.5.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.4.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.4.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.4.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.4.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.3.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.3.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.3.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.3.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.3.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.3.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.2.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.2.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.2.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.2.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.2.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.2.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.1.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.1.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.1.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.1.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.1.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.1.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.1.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.0.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.0.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.0.4 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.0.3 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.0.2 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.0.1 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 8.0.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- Installation request for phpunit/phpunit ^8 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[8.0.0, 8.0.1, 8.0.2, 8.0.3, 8.0.4, 8.0.5, 8.0.6, 8.1.0, 8.1.1, 8.1.2, 8.1.3, 8.1.4, 8.1.5, 8.1.6, 8.2.0, 8.2.1, 8.2.2, 8.2.3, 8.2.4, 8.2.5, 8.3.0, 8.3.1, 8.3.2, 8.3.3, 8.3.4, 8.3.5, 8.4.0, 8.4.1, 8.4.2, 8.4.3, 8.5.0, 8.5.1, 8.5.2].
```

So I installed the missing dependency - PHP extension dom:

```
sudo apt install php-dom
```

Next time I ran `composer install` it completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

clear composer cache

```
composer clear-cache
```