# Install Laravel without Composer

Tags: php, laravel, dependencies, composer-php

I'm not allowed to install Composer on my server at work. Bureaucracy! Also, it's not connected to the internet. It's a company intranet server and I'm not a sys admin for it.

Am I going to experience high levels of difficulty installing and running Laravel without Composer? Should I use another Framework?

I'm quite a basic PHP programmer without too much command line experience to be honest. I'm used to having everything I need for a project contained in one directory - like CodeIgniter for example.

[This article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825227/laravel-composer-install-hangs-on-installing-dependencies-and-consume-a-lot-of) is suggesting that there are quite a few required dependencies. Will my Laravel project just fail to run properly without them?

-- UPDATE --

If by chance, there is a way to do it without Composer, then please tell me how I can do this. I downloaded the source files for Laravel from GitHub (like you would do with CodeIgniter) but I get errors when I try and view it on a browser;

```
Warning: require(/var/www/html/test/laravel/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/test/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/html/test/laravel/bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/php/includes:/var/www/html/php/includes:/jpa/release/jpa/includes:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php/phpmailer:/apache/htdocs/applications/surveys/Includes:/var/lib/ZF1/library') in /var/www/html/test/laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php on line 17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess one way would be to run composer on another machine(maybe at home). Then just take all the files that composer downloads and move it to your work machine.

Installing it manually is a lot of work. You have to do all the stuff that composer does in the background effectively. Following all the dependencies will be super hard.

Comment: Actually... I do have Laravel up and running on my mac at home. I did so using Composer. I wasn't sure if all the dependencies that Composer "fetches" are put in to that Laravel folder or if they are placed on the server in some random config file.

Comment: Oh okay. No yeah. They are all put in the laravel folder. So you can move that folder across machines. No problem.

Comment: Wow. Thanks guy. I will try this and see what happens!